# How to compose Linq 'or' query by iterating over collection of string search parameters

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a list of string based search parameters:

i.e. {"partialName1", "partialName2", "partialName3", ..., "partialName(N)"}
I won't ever know what size N is before hand.

I would like to compose a Linq (Linq-to-Entities) "OR" query by iterating over this collection of strings and compose a query equivalent to the query below:

```
var specialFolk = people.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("partialName1") || p.Name.Contains("partialName2") || p.Name.Contains("partialName3") || ... || p.Name.Contains("partialName(N)"));
```

The following code demonstrates what I want to do.  But it will not work, it is only an illustration of the concept I want to use to build an OR query in a composable way

```
        List<string> searchPhrases = searchPhraseGiveToUsFromAbove;

        IQueryable<Person> personQuery;
        foreach(string searchPhrase in searchPhrases)
        {
            personQuery = personQuery.Where(p=>p.Name.Contains(searchPhrase))
        }
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6):

You should compare it in opposite manner like:

```
var query = personQuery.Where(p => searchPhrases.Any(r=> p.Name.Contains(r));
```

Comment: In LINQ-to-objects this would be great. In LINQ-to-Entities the `Any` creates a SQL phrase that quickly exceeds maximum nesting level. Ac couple of tens of elements in `searchPhrases` is enough to cause this.

Comment: @GertArnold is there a better way?

Comment: @John Maybe composing a query by a predicate builder (chain OR statements). Sometimes `Union` comes tot the rescue. Each alternative should be investigated wrt performance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks goes to @GertArnold I found my way through his comment regarding predicate builder.

A quick bing on "c# linq composing a query by a predicate builder"

And I found a "linq" to LINQKit : http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Now I know that SO does not like links as answers, but I am not sure if I would be plagiarising (some advice on that would be useful)

The predicate builder is very cool and makes it easy to compose queries programmatically (copied from the albahari [website](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)):

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Then there is a comment 'If querying with Entity Framework, change the last line to this:'

```
return objectContext.Products.AsExpandable().Where (predicate);
```

However I wanted to chain these predicates into something more complex, and I got stumped by an error:

> The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

This led me to a blog by [Pete Montgomery](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/author/petemontgomery/) titled a [universal predicate builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/)

It turns out as Pete explains, that the Albahari version does not play well with Entity framework due to a reliance on InvocationExpressions. Pete's blog on this is well worth the read if you are using EF.

Again I don't want to just copy and paste his solution (it's his and he offers it free) but I will show the query I was able to build which ultimately solved my problem:

```
private IQueryable<Show> BuildQueryForLibrarySearchTerms(IEnumerable<LibraryShowSearchTerm> searchTerms)
    {

        IQueryable<Show> query = _repository.Get();

        IEnumerable<LibraryShowSearchTerm> includeTerms = searchTerms.Where(st=>st.Exclude.Equals(false));
        IEnumerable<LibraryShowSearchTerm> excludeTerms = searchTerms.Where(st=>st.Exclude.Equals(true));

        var predicate = LinqPredicateBuilder.False<Show>();

        var includePredicate = LinqPredicateBuilder.False<Show>();
        foreach (LibraryShowSearchTerm searchTerm in includeTerms)
        {
            string temp = searchTerm.SearchTerm;
            includePredicate = includePredicate.Or(show => show.ShowTitle.Contains(temp));
        }

        var excludePredicate = LinqPredicateBuilder.True<Show>();
        foreach (LibraryShowSearchTerm searchTerm in excludeTerms)
        {
            string temp = searchTerm.SearchTerm;
            excludePredicate = excludePredicate.And(show => !show.ShowTitle.Contains(temp));
        }

        predicate = includePredicate.And(excludePredicate);
        return query.Where(predicate);
    }
```

Although I have given this as an answer, and it is. I am not marking it as such since it is not my answer to give,  if either Pete or Joseph(Albahari) come across this and wish to create an answer, I will mark it as such.